# What's the difference between Angular2-all.umd.js and angular2.js

Tags: javascript, angular

At this moment Angular 2 is in its 13th beta. When I look at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/ I can see that there are 2 different versions of Angular2:

- angular2-all.umd.js
- angular2.js

What's the difference between the two? And apperently the angular2.js doesn't have an angular2.umd.js version, why is this?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/bundles/overview.md

Comment: @EricMartinez 404. Better to post relevant info than a link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, `angular2-all.umd.js` must be used if you want to implement Angular2 applications with ES5.

`angular2.js` is the core module to implement Angular2 applications with ES6 or TypeScript. This file must be used along with a module manager like SystemJS.

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, strange they have no clear documentation about that. Besides the naming of the files is not clear as well i.m.o.

Comment: In fact, I know that the Angular2 team works on the documentation regarding building such applications with ES5... Sure this will be improved in the future ;-)

Comment: Hey @ThierryTemplier, when I look in my `systemjs.config.js` file from the latest angular 2 quickstart, I see that the npm packages referenced in the `map` object for the angular bundles is as follows:

`'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js'`
so I was hoping whether you could clarify; I'm using TypeScript/ES6 to write my application, does that mean `systemjs` never gets used? Or is it used in addition to the typescript compiler to convert ES6 down into ES5 for use in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above for ES5 one should use UMD modules: `angular2-all.umd.js` and `Rx.umd.js`. For Typescript or ES6, use `angular2.js` and `Rx.js` (they also require `system.js`).

As an educational exercise one can also use ES6 style modules with ES5:
(https://jsfiddle.net/8g5809rg/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2.js"></script>

<script>

System.import("angular2/core").then(function(core) {

  ParentComponent.annotations = [
    new core.Component({
      selector: 'body',
      template: '<div (click)="go()">Parent</div><child [prop1]="x"></child>',
      directives: [ChildComponent]
    })
  ];

  function ParentComponent() {
    this.x = "hello1"
  }

  ParentComponent.prototype.go = function() {
    this.x += "1"
  };

  ///

  ChildComponent.annotations = [
    new core.Component({
      selector: 'child',
      inputs: ["prop1"],
      template: '<div>Child {{prop1}}</div>',
      changeDetection: core.ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
  ];

  function ChildComponent() {
  }

  ////////////////

  System.import("angular2/platform/browser").then(function(browser) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      browser.bootstrap(ParentComponent);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```